# How can I sort a cursor or sqlite database by date with different formats?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to sort my data by increasing date on the list View.
Depending on the user's settings, the saved dates are followed as following
`DD.MM.YYYY` or `MMM DD, YYYY`. Right now the order is set to "date ASC".

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(EventEntry.CONTENT_URI,
           projection, null, null, "date ASC");
```

So as I sort by ascending date, 26.07.2019 would be displayed above 31.03.2019 despite being later. In the american format, the sorting doesn't work anyways as for example Apr is always shown above any other month. I'd like to support both date formats for a better user experience.

Is there any way to sort the dates in the cursor or the database in the correct order?

Comment: Change the format of the dates in the table to `YYYY-MM-DD` so that it is comparable. SQLite stores dates as strings.

Comment: I thought about that too, but I'd like the date not to be displayed in that format, as it is not really common and thus maybe confusing...

Comment: Personally, I'd favour storing the dates in a consistent format (i.e. epoch millis, as they can be easily sorted) and applying any user formatting settings after that information has been retrieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will change the format of the date to `YYYYMMDD` in the `order by` argument:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    EventEntry.CONTENT_URI,
    projection, null, null, 
    "substr(date, 7) || substr(date, 4, 2) || substr(date, 1, 2) ASC");
```

But the problem of date comparing will remain. 
The best thing to do is either change the format of the dates to `YYYY-MM-DD` or store the dates as integers (epoch milis).

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your date to timestamp before sorting.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(EventEntry.CONTENT_URI,
           projection, null, null, "strftime('%s', date) ASC");
```

Comment: The dates are stored in `DD.MM.YYYY` format, so `strftime('%s', date)` will return `null`.

Comment: Sorry, I jumped the gun too quickly. As others mentioned above, converting your dates to a consistent format - one that is supported by sqlite - would help you achieve this. If it doesn't require too much work then I'd definitely suggest that solution too.